# Java Reflection - Invoke valueOf on different types

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to invoke the valueOf method on different types such as Integer, String,... using reflection.

I want to know how to call this method using reflection with only one `getMehod()`.

The problem is when the type is `java.lang.String` the `valueOf` method doesn't accept the String parameter and when it is Integer or other types the valueOf method  doesn't accept the `Object.class` .

I used one if clause to differentiate them as you can see below but I want to remove the if clause.

```
private static void setFieldValue(String fieldName, String fieldValue, Rule rule) throws Exception {
        Field field = Rule.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Class<?> type = field.getType();
        Method valueOf;

        // here I checked the type

        if (String.class.equals(type))
            valueOf = type.getMethod("valueOf", Object.class);
        else
            valueOf = type.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
        field.set(rule, valueOf.invoke(null, fieldValue));
}
```

Comment: if (String.class.equals(type)) {
            field.set(rule, fieldValue);
        } else {
            Method valueOf = type.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
            field.set(rule, valueOf.invoke(null, fieldValue));
        }

Please update the if-else code with the above and also remove the  Method valueOf;
Seems, this is happening due to the overloading of the "valueOf" method for different params and different classes.
Please try once.

Comment: Try finding the String version first and if not found look for Object version.

Comment: You'll need to convert the _type_ for _primitive data-types_.  This isn't a practical application; is there a specific functionality you're looking to use, or just practicing code?

Comment: @HarishDalmia, Thanks, I did it. it's shorter and better but Is there any solution to avoid using if clause?

Comment: @Reilas, I'm trying to read an Excel file and map it to a POJO.

Comment: @Mojtaba - Yes, we can use try-catch. In the try block, we can use String. class and when it fails and proceeds to catch block there we can log the error if needed and use Object.class. Will add code to the solution. Thanks

Comment: @Mojtaba writing correct reflection based code is always tricky and error prone, try to use existing library like apache beanutils which solves problem easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the types constructor (with String arg) instead of the valueOf method :

```
static class Rule {
    private String stringField;
    private Integer integerField;
    private Double doubleField;
    private Long longField;
    private Boolean booleanField;
    private BigDecimal bigDecimalField;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Rule rule = new Rule();
    setFieldValue(rule, "stringField", "string val");
    setFieldValue(rule, "integerField", "12");
    setFieldValue(rule, "doubleField", "1.23");
    setFieldValue(rule, "longField", "19877754");
    setFieldValue(rule, "booleanField", "false");
    setFieldValue(rule, "bigDecimalField", "879565.3565754");
    System.out.println(rule.stringField);
    System.out.println(rule.integerField);
    System.out.println(rule.doubleField);
    System.out.println(rule.longField);
    System.out.println(rule.booleanField);
    System.out.println(rule.bigDecimalField);
}

private static void setFieldValue(Rule rule, String fieldName, String fieldValue) throws Exception {
    Field field = Rule.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Class<?> type = field.getType();
    Constructor<?> valueOf = type.getConstructor(String.class);
    field.set(rule, valueOf.newInstance(fieldValue));
}
```

Output :

```
string val
12
1.23
19877754
false
879565.3565754
```

Comment: Some of the invoked constructors have been marked “*Deprecated, for removal*”, see for example [`Double(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) or [`Integer(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)). So, don’t be surprised when this code stops working with a future Java version.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comment, if we want to avoid using the if clause - we can try using try catch to achieve. Below is the updated code.

```
private static void setFieldValue(String fieldName, String fieldValue, Rule rule) throws Exception {
    Field field = Rule.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Class<?> type = field.getType();
    Method valueOf;
    try {
        valueOf = type.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        valueOf = type.getMethod("valueOf", Object.class);
    }
   field.set(rule, valueOf.invoke(null, fieldValue));
}
```

Please try and update. Thank you.